# com.chaquo.python.PyException: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.flipkart.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, python-3.x, android-studio, max, retrywhen

When I install a python programe in android mobile via android studio.Following error appears and my app crashes.

```
com.chaquo.python.PyException: ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.flipkart.com', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /cello-novelty-big-plastic-free-standing-chest- 
drawers/p/itm30f968c84bc68? 
pid=CSDEFFMN2Y7ZDUGQ&lid=LSTCSDEFFMN2Y7ZDUGQ6GF2RX&marketplace=FLIPKART&pageUID=1603005810862 (Caused 
by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x898b8a78>: Failed to establish 
a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))
```

This app is to take the url of a product from the user and check product price.

Answer (score 1):

In AndroidManifest.xml write line to take permission to use internet by the application.

This problem is due you are not getting internet access by the phone to your app.

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```